# how to exit from a function without return in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I have this function

```js
function deleteItem() {
   deleteInvItems({
        where: {
            invoice_id: invData.invNo,
            [Op.not]: [{
                item_id: itemIDs
            }]
        }
    }).then(resp => {      
        if (!resp) return false;
    });
    
    deleteInvSumItems([{
        where: {
            invoice_id: invData.invNo,              
            [Op.not]: [{
                hsn_code: invUniqueHsnCodes
            }]
        }
    }]).then(resp => {      
        if (!resp) return false;
    });
    
    return true;
}
```

I want to exit the function with `return false;` if I get `false` response from server.

But if I call inner functions without `return keyword` unlike `return deleteInvItems({...})` and `return deleteInvSumItems({...})`. I'm not able to exit the parent function.

How can I exit the parent function `deleteItem()` with retuning `false` if I get `false` response from server?

Comment: [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321)

Comment: Where does ```resp``` come from and what do you mean with exit the parent function? What happens - infinite loop or an error?

Comment: Are you looking to only run deleteInvSumItems if deleteInvItems doesn't fail? i.e. is the purpose of the `if (!resp) return false;` in the then() callback of deleteInvItems to stop deleteInvSumItems from running?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to use the [async/await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await) syntax instead of `Promise.then(...)`.

```
async function deleteItem() {
  try {
    const response = await deleteInvSumItems(...)    // pass parameters here
    if(!response) {
      // since this is not part of an inner callback function
      // it will exit the deleteItem function
      return       
     }
   } catch (err) {
     // handle error
   }
```

Note: `async/await` is supported since ECMAScript 2017, so make sure your platform where you run your code supports it.

Answer (score 0):

Your function needs to be async:

```
async function deleteItem() {
   const res = await deleteInvItems({
        where: {
            invoice_id: invData.invNo,
            [Op.not]: [{
                item_id: itemIDs
            }]
        }
    })
// do something with res
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since your code is asynchronous, you can't "just" exit the function.

You have to work with [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise), or with [Async/Await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function).

If you choose to work with promises, just return the promise, and use `then`.

I think that since your code needs to stop the `then` chain with 2 promises (`deleteInvItems` and `deleteInvSumItems`), it's easier and readable to use `async await` here:

```js
//when you call the function, use await to get the result:
let finalResult = await deleteItem();

async function deleteItem() {
  let val1 = await deleteInvItems({
    where: {
      invoice_id: invData.invNo,
      [Op.not]: [{
        item_id: itemIDs
      }]
    }
  }).then(resp => {
    if (!resp) return false;
  });
  let val2 = await deleteInvSumItems([{
    where: {
      invoice_id: invData.invNo,
      [Op.not]: [{
        hsn_code: invUniqueHsnCodes
      }]
    }
  }]).then(resp => {
    if (!resp) return false;
  });

  return val1 && val2;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Use the break statement with a label reference, to "jump out" of a nested for loop:

```js
 let text = "";
 let i;
     mainLoop:
   for (let k = 0; k < 5; k++) {
     for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
       if (i === 3) {
         break mainLoop;
       }
       text += "The number is " + i + "<br>";
     }
   }
 document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text;
```

```html
<p id="demo"></p>
```

Answer (score -3):

You can use break method for exiting in a function in js .
for eg :

```js
const getName = () => {
  getName: {
    console.log("I get logged");

    break getName;

    //exits the function

    console.log("I don't get logged");
  }
};
```